# Can somebody help me understand why this JavaScript code won't work, and how I can fix it?

Tags: javascript, variables, local-storage

I'm trying make a global points bank for a project, and I've been trying to get a basic prototype of what I need made.

I've asked a question on how I can save a variable, and I got one answer that was OK, however, it didn't seem to work, and it would probably be better if I was to just ask a new question instead of spending a bunch of time talking in the comments with one person.

My problem is that when I press the button, it doesn't update.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript variable testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="tex/javascript">
var clicks = 500000;

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks); // update the value
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

  localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks); // set the value to localStorage
};

window.onload = function() {
  clicks = localStorage.getItem('clicks'); // get the value from localStorage
};
        </script>
        <button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click this bit</button>
            <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">500000</a>
            </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also, if anybody could make their code so the variable stays the same, even for people who are using a different computer, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You have a typo on the script type. Also you at setting the value in localstorage twice

Comment: Inside window.onload you should update the dom element with the number of clicks

Comment: Oh. I'm a little new to javascript, so I'm not sure how to do that, could you explain please?

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled in script type. Correct it to: `<script type="text/javascript">`

Reffering to your comment, I would do it in this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clicks; // variable initialization

    function onClick() {
      clicks = +clicks + 1; // + operator casts value to number
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
      localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks); // set the value to localStorage
    };

    window.onload = function() {
      clicks = localStorage.getItem('clicks') || 500000; // get the value from localStorage, otherwise (if is null) set 500000 clicks
      document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Cheers, but it simply puts a '1' to the end of my number instead of adding 1 to the value, and it doesn't remain the same when I refresh.

Comment: `clicks` needed to be casted to a `number`. I updated my answer.

Comment: THANK YOU! However, I must ask, does the value stay the same accross different computers?

Comment: `localStorage` is, as its name says, stored locally (in the browser). You can even edit its values in Developer tools -> Resources -> Local Storage. If you want this value to be shared, you need to save it in your server, but it's a material for another question.

Comment: I added some comments to make it easier to understand. If you have no doubts please choose the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Small Mistake In Code otherwise everything is fine**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript variable testing</title>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript"> // Small misspelled
var clicks = 500000;

function onClick() {
  clicks += 1;
  localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks); // update the value
  document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

  localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks); // set the value to localStorage
} // Removed semicolon you added by mistake

window.onload = function() {
  clicks = localStorage.getItem('clicks'); // get the value from localStorage
};
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click this bit</button>
<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">500000</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a t,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
```

Seems to be working after that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `tex/javascript` to `text/javascript`.
2. You have to `parseInt()` the value from localstorage (else it's a string).

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Javascript variable testing</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var clicks;

      function onClick() {
        clicks += 1;
        localStorage.setItem('clicks', clicks); // update the value
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = clicks;
      }

      window.onload = function() {
        clicks = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('clicks')) || 500000; // get the value from localStorage and parse it to int
        document.getElementById('clicks').innerHTML = clicks;
      };

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button type="button" onclick="onClick()">Click this bit</button>
    <p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">500000</a>
    </p>
  </body>

</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0urbgq94/3/)

Comment: I tried that, but umm, as soon as I pressed the button... "Clicks: 5.000001111111111e+24"